# Problems with Polygon Reshape Feature

Tags: qgis, polygon

I've created a polygon and closed my project, after opening the project again, i can't use the Reshape Feature tool in that specific polygon. But if I create a new polygon in the same shapefile I can use this tool.

Do you know what can be happening in my project? what can I do?

Comment: I'm trying to guess what might have gone wrong here, but make sure you have no feature selected in your active editable layer OR that you have selected (at least) the feature you want to reshape.

Comment: i've tryed, and still doesn't work, this is pretty strange, it's the first time that happen to me.

Comment: See if you have some invalid features. You can do it with Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Geometry validity

Comment: thanks Alexandre Neto! it appears to be a lot of errors... It says that "contains duplicate node(s)" how can i avoid this kind o errors and how can i correct them no that i have all my shape done?

Comment: Forget it! i've already solve my problem! Thanks a lot for you're help guys, it was very helpful :)

Comment: Please post a solution to the answer so that it can be closed out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to toggle the editing tab.  Once you've done this, the Reshape Features tab should become active.

[image]

Comment: Yes, i know that, but after i toggle the editing tab i've try to reshape the polygon and nothing appends, and that is my problem.

Answer (score -1):

first select feature then click on reshape then reshape feature Since the beginning of the feature

Comment: I think the user is aware of how to use the reshape tool, I suspect that the problem goes deeper than just an inability to find/use a tool - considering the user *can* reshape a polygon in that session. This is more likely to be a Scratch Workspace / main database problem... good try though.